# Network call from native module instead from Javascript/React Native

Tags: react-native, networking, xmlhttprequest

I want to know how to make a network request on app initialization from the native modules instead of doing it in Javacsript/React Native code.

I saw in a video that one way to speed up the initialization time is to move the network requests to the native-modules (iOS/Android), that way when the app is ready the response of the network request is given to React-Native to handle it.

The video is titled ["Performance in React Native" by Ram Narasimhan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nphKGWjhg2M). There is no example provided.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I made for both iOS and Android: https://github.com/corinaferencz/network-native-module

Network requests are handled in native, and the response is sent to React Native.